# failed to load wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, error-log

I get this error when i try to open my wallet: 
     $ ./monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file home/samuel/wallet/wallet2
     Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.2.0-38b9226)
     Logging to ./monero-wallet-cli.log 
     Wallet password: *****************
     Error: failed to load wallet: file not found "home/samuel/wallet/wallet2.keys

What am I doing wrong here? 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Absolute paths in linux start with `/`. So it seems you are missing `/`in your path. It should be `/home/samuel/wallet/wallet2`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing an `/`

Try:

`./monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file /home/samuel/wallet/wallet2`

You can also use `~` instead of your home dir:

`./monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file ~/wallet/wallet2`